# Connecting https site responseHeader delays

Tags: performance, ssl, web-crawler, okhttp

I made an app that depends on latest news and one part of it need to bring country specific news just to have some latest news article on the site. I chosen world.einnews.com as they have really nice country specific layout, they also provide RSS but you have to subscribe for each countries on their site where they generate a rss link.
I took shortcut and directly go to their site and read what I need. It was ok for few weeks now I started to see the delay in receiving response from that site, just before I decided to go live.

Below is my okhttp event listener log and you can see the delay always occurs when responseHeader starts

```
0.000 callStart
0.001 connectionAcquired
0.001 requestHeadersStart
0.002 requestHeadersEnd
0.002 responseHeadersStart
86.383 responseHeadersEnd
86.799 responseBodyStart
87.817 responseBodyEnd
87.977 connectionReleased
87.998 callEnd
```

Now this has been my situation so looks like something goes on when SSL handshake is attempted I tried curl and got this output :

```
 curl -G https://world.einnews.com/country/burkinafaso -v -e www.google.com -k
* About to connect() to world.einnews.com port 443 (#0)
* Trying 173.203.107.183...
* Connected to world.einnews.com (173.203.107.183) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=*.einnews.com
*   start date: Feb 17 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*   expire date: Mar 18 12:00:00 2021 GMT
*   common name: *.einnews.com
*   issuer: CN=Thawte RSA CA 2018,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US
> GET /country/burkinafaso HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: world.einnews.com
> Accept: */*
> Referer: www.google.com
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Fri, 16 Oct 2020 19:09:54 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 209078
< Connection: keep-alive
< Keep-Alive: timeout=10
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Status: 200 OK
< Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only: default-src https: data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; 
 report-uri /csp_reports
< Expires: Thu, 15 Oct 2020 19:09:52 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Set-Cookie: ein_visit=1602875392%3AjrJa9zNl7kWh1O4JiDEY894a2IJ- 
 eRnsMhow4fJAeHyPzerWcCrYBn7xgrN82ktxe90__N-BL73l4y4w_UJVj-ycYbubg- 
 Ew9wAin5pFxdycFXl9lwDEqb4KVYtlq_lEhCvW2JDWoIsV9SxNXVsWOsfrrbZSDL8rtyGjAmVnlPV1TI- 
 XovsUf722O06qIPqJcgtupdjxgHzptJ3t0sCtcBw39Vd2EkxTxVzxhNK0o- 
< Set-Cookie: ein_ags=gLLGYrJqzY4BCiOT%3A1602875392%3A1602875392; domain=einnews.com; path=/; 
expires=Sat, 17-Oct-2020 13:09:52 GMT
< Set-Cookie: 
prev_nav_1=qZvmCmbfK7v3yxTY+1602875392+worldnews+%2Fcountry%2Fburkinafaso+Burkina+Faso+Newswire; 
domain=einnews.com; path=/; expires=Sat, 17-Oct-2020 19:09:52 GMT
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Etag: "02c6c59d2763f21d92d95d686866a473"
< Set-Cookie: uid=AgAAAALwiV/RLE+xAYMFRw==; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; domain=.einnews.com; 
path=/
<
```

Even curl takes long time I am really at my wits end I tried trust all ssl before making call, I also tried to use different user agent and other parameters but I cannot figure out why site respond slow.

I only need to hit once and cache the result for a day so that I can avoid network trip, it was ok initially but now I have long delays but sometime its quicker.  If I visit the site through browser normally site is fast only headless browsing is a pain.

Any tips and tricks to speed up this?

Comment: How are you measuring in a browser? Can you even detect 86ms with your eyes in a browser request?

It sounds like the site just takes 86ms to generate a response.  In most HTTP web frameworks, you need the body generated before you can set a response (200, response headers + body).

Comment: Thats not ms thats second, please check okhttp listener [event](https://square.github.io/okhttp/events/)

Comment: There is not enough information to go on from the question.  No sample code to reproduce the problem. It could just be an overloaded server when you make a large number of concurrent calls to it from a single server.

Comment: Have you had any progress in solving this?
I have the same problem here!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that sort of delay.  There is a lot more debugging you can enable to see HTTP/2 frames, and even the thread pool activity in OkHttp.  This is a test client that shows that same request for me.

The java.util loggers that might be interesting are

okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2
okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner

```
$  okurl --debug https://world.einnews.com/country/burkinafaso
13:50:48.596    url https://world.einnews.com/country/burkinafaso
13:50:48.598    Request Request{method=GET, url=https://world.einnews.com/country/burkinafaso, headers=[User-Agent:okurl/dev OkHttp/4.10.0-RC1], tags={class com.baulsupp.okurl.credentials.Token=TokenSet(name=default)}}
13:50:48.634    Dns (world.einnews.com): world.einnews.com/173.203.107.183, world.einnews.com/173.203.107.239
13:50:49.126    Q10002 scheduled after   5 s : OkHttp world.einnews.com ping
13:50:49.127    >> CONNECTION 505249202a20485454502f322e300d0a0d0a534d0d0a0d0a
13:50:49.127    >> 0x00000000     6 SETTINGS
13:50:49.127    >> 0x00000000     4 WINDOW_UPDATE
13:50:49.127    Q10005 scheduled after   0 Ás: OkHttp world.einnews.com
13:50:49.128    Q10005 starting              : OkHttp world.einnews.com
13:50:49.128    Q10001 scheduled after   0 Ás: OkHttp ConnectionPool
13:50:49.128    --> GET https://world.einnews.com/country/burkinafaso h2
13:50:49.128    User-Agent: okurl/dev OkHttp/4.10.0-RC1
13:50:49.128    Accept-Encoding: br,gzip
13:50:49.128    Host: world.einnews.com
13:50:49.128    Connection: Keep-Alive
13:50:49.128    --> END GET
13:50:49.128    Q10001 starting              : OkHttp ConnectionPool
13:50:49.128    << 0x00000000    18 SETTINGS
13:50:49.128    Q10001 run again after 300 s : OkHttp ConnectionPool
13:50:49.128    Q10001 finished run in 534 Ás: OkHttp ConnectionPool
13:50:49.128    Q10002 scheduled after   0 Ás: OkHttp world.einnews.com applyAndAckSettings
13:50:49.129    << 0x00000000     4 WINDOW_UPDATE
13:50:49.129    Q10002 starting              : OkHttp world.einnews.com applyAndAckSettings
13:50:49.129    Q10004 scheduled after   0 Ás: OkHttp world.einnews.com onSettings
13:50:49.129    >> 0x00000000     0 SETTINGS      ACK
13:50:49.129    Matching interceptor: null
13:50:49.129    Q10004 starting              : OkHttp world.einnews.com onSettings
13:50:49.129    Q10002 finished run in 453 Ás: OkHttp world.einnews.com applyAndAckSettings
13:50:49.129    Q10004 finished run in 262 Ás: OkHttp world.einnews.com onSettings
13:50:49.129    >> 0x00000003    65 HEADERS       END_STREAM|END_HEADERS
13:50:49.379    << 0x00000000     0 SETTINGS      ACK
13:50:52.142    << 0x00000003   955 HEADERS       END_HEADERS
13:50:52.142    << 0x00000003  8192 DATA
13:50:52.142    <-- 200 https://world.einnews.com/country/burkinafaso (3014ms)
13:50:52.142    << 0x00000003  8192 DATA
13:50:52.142    server: nginx
13:50:52.142    date: Sun, 18 Oct 2020 12:50:52 GMT
13:50:52.143    content-type: text/html
13:50:52.143    vary: Accept-Encoding
13:50:52.143    vary: Accept-Encoding
13:50:52.143    status: 200 OK
13:50:52.143    content-security-policy-report-only: default-src https: data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; report-uri /csp_reports
13:50:52.143    expires: Sat, 17 Oct 2020 12:50:51 GMT
13:50:52.143    cache-control: no-cache
13:50:52.143    set-cookie: ein_ags=k4mN99M2gOHvl8kp%3A1603025451%3A1603025451; domain=einnews.com; path=/; expires=Mon, 19-Oct-2020 06:50:51 GMT
13:50:52.143    set-cookie: ein_visit=1603025451%3AngzpmQnb9_71Sm9SVQL5aW9oh0fr9UUdqU9fGmUNQR0TedOpAZyAzRLiqmE_sF4XkU7esQ4PAojbnsynVCVtoOwLkcoXNnBjq95q7zmbCi9mJbNhdS6x_phE2tcjtrS1FVZI1O1cyc1_zlZy8twjRvAAUm1BSp4MHpbzlzEu6ROySFESHRTlimi560THEByAnCVrWoeTgV_QloTZZgV29Azjr-qEeBpGiF35_2TihnBNTb6Ptddt_X3nYmknHbv27XKKB8UGVs3iDwFL6_oX7NnO-smkTeMdvdlnGMLesQOCc9d6uoiwmM613UPHi79gwW4HJ2_NCxneE244536FZw%3D%3D; domain=einnews.com; path=/; expires=Fri, 17-Oct-2025 12:50:51 GMT
13:50:52.143    set-cookie: prev_nav_1=yXmftb5d13-tVPZa+1603025451+worldnews+%2Fcountry%2Fburkinafaso+Burkina+Faso+Newswire; domain=einnews.com; path=/; expires=Mon, 19-Oct-2020 12:50:51 GMT
13:50:52.144    x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
13:50:52.144    etag: W/"b6c4cf414dc0fc83bf1b1cb2ba803dd5"
13:50:52.144    set-cookie: uid=BgAAACw6jF9vKk55AQJrLQ==; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; domain=.einnews.com; path=/
13:50:52.144    content-encoding: gzip
13:50:52.144    <-- END HTTP
13:50:52.144    OkHttp Platform: Jdk9Platform
13:50:52.144    Protocol: h2
13:50:52.144    TLS Version: TLS_1_2
13:50:52.144    Cipher: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
13:50:52.145    Peer Principal: CN=*.einnews.com
13:50:52.145    Local Principal: none
13:50:52.145    JVM: GraalVM 20.2.0 Java 11
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```